# php curl with header modify

Tags: php, curl, header

I am testing a flow where i need to spoof ip and mobile number to test. The problem is **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**. The header value i am sending is not accessible by the link. Below is my code.

```
<?php
    $cookie_file = '/tmp/checkcookie';
    $url = "https://example.com/someparameter=value";

    $ip = '10.18.25.123';
    $msisdn = '9878656565';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Forwarded-For: $ip','MSISDN: $msisdn'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Any idea what to change. Thanks

Comment: Well yes, there's no standard header for spoofing a phone number. Generally HTTP does not use phone numbers. Nor can you spoof the sending IP address (apart from the faux proxy header you tried). Unless you elaborate on the API being targetted (example.com tells nobody nothing), this is unanswerable without a sample raw HTTP request to emulate. The onus of figuring out how to overcome access restrictions is on you.

Comment: ok bro thnx will figure out